# How can I successfully install Ubuntu 12.10 next to windows 7

Tags: installation, 12.10, dual-boot

I have an installation of Windows 7 and I would like to install Ubuntu 12.10 side by side.

During the installation of Ubuntu GRUB comes up with an error and gives me the option to select which disk it should be installed to. I have always found this difficult as I am never sure which disk to select. In my case I see one with "Windows bootloader". I was guessing that was the boot disk for my system but having selected it and completing the Ubuntu installation, GRUB did not appear and Windows loaded. I had no way to get to my Ubuntu installation.

I then tried another disk for GRUB after receiving the same message on a re-install of Ubuntu but it didn't work either. In stead of fumbling about I thought I would ask here.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Do you use different partitions or differsnt harddisks?

Answer (score 1):

If you are unsure about partitions I wouldn't even install it. My recommendation is to install it inside windows like a program, this way you don't risk overwriting your partitions. I found this link http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer

Comment: Hmmm...the strange thing is, it has worked with my current partitioning.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use this guide http://www.ehow.com/how_5133222_see-hard-drive-partitions.html to sort out on wich partition windows is stored. Another way is to use an ubuntu live cd and test (instead of installing it) Ubuntu. With Ubuntu, use GParted to check and manage your partitions. Then you can just install ubuntu from the live cd.

Good luck =)